# Start Activity clearing top in Android

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I have the following Activities in my stack:

```
A , B , C, D
```

I want to relaunch B in order to get this stack:

```
A , B'
```

Where B' is a new B instance (not the old receiving a onNewIntent callback, how can I do it?

By the way I'm using a

```
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
```

when launching the B activity but this way the onNewIntent is called instead of start a new instance

Comment: explain your question more

Comment: Post your manifest. Have you defined activity B with `launchMode="singleTop"`? Starting activity B with `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` is the correct way to do this, so it should work as you've described. There must be something else going wrong.

Comment: @AndroidDeveloper I think this question is perfectly well explained. What else do you need to know?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use android:noHistory=true in manifest file for particular activity to clear.Hope this might solve your issue.

Comment: How exactly do you think this will help? OP says he wants to launch B from activity D and have it remove B, C and D from the activity stack and create a new instance of B. If he sets `android:noHistory="true"` for some activities, then the BACK key won't function properly and this will not help solve the stated problem.

Answer (score 2):

here when you use this code the its take you on activity B. in B you Press backbutton the its take you on A.

```
Intent fromDtoB = new Intent(this,B.class);
fromDtoB.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(fromDtoB);
```

FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK: If set in an Intent passed to Context.startActivity(), this flag will cause any existing task that would be associated with the activity to be cleared before the activity is started.

FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP: If set, and the activity being launched is already running in the current task, then instead of launching a new instance of that activity, all of the other activities on top of it will be closed and this Intent will be delivered to the (now on top) old activity as a new Intent.

Comment: OP already said that he is using `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP`, but it isn't working. Just quoting from the documentation is unlikely to fix his problem.

Comment: @DavidWasser: because its working without add android:noHistory=true in manifest. just try..