# Finish Activity in BackStack - Android

Tags: android, android-activity

In my app I have activities A, B, C, D and E. First activity is A then opening B and then C and D. Now my back stack is A-B-C-D. Now when I move to E from D I want to finish all the activity in back stack and now E should be the first activity in stack.

In my case

```
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
```

or

```
android:launchMode="singleTask"
```

didn't work, because I am not reopening an activity which is already opened. I have to close all the activity in backstack while opening a new activity.

Please help me to do this.

Comment: See my answer, if you have any doubt then please ask me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edited final answer**

**ActivitA  Important**

```
    import java.util.Calendar;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlarmManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;

import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;


public class ActivityA extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getIntent().getBooleanExtra("EXIT", false)) {
            startActivity(new Intent(ActivityA.this,ActivityE.class));
            finish();
        }  

        setContentView(R.layout.alayout);

        Button play;

        play = (Button) findViewById(R.id.aId);     

        play.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override

        public void onClick(View v) {

            startActivity(new Intent(ActivityA.this,ActivityB.class));

        }

        });


    }

}
```

**ActivityB**

```
    import java.util.Calendar;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlarmManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;

import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;


public class ActivityB extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getIntent().getBooleanExtra("EXIT", false)) {
            finish();
        }  

        setContentView(R.layout.blayout);

        Button play;

        play = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bId);     

        play.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override

        public void onClick(View v) {

            startActivity(new Intent(ActivityB.this,ActivityC.class));

        }

        });


    }

}
```

**ActivityC**

```
import java.util.Calendar;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlarmManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;

import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;


public class ActivityC extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getIntent().getBooleanExtra("EXIT", false)) {
            finish();
        }  

        setContentView(R.layout.clayout);

        Button play;

        play = (Button) findViewById(R.id.cId);     

        play.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override

        public void onClick(View v) {

            startActivity(new Intent(ActivityC.this,ActivityD.class));

        }

        });


    }

}
```

**ActivityD   Important**

```
import java.util.Calendar;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlarmManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;

import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;


public class ActivityD extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getIntent().getBooleanExtra("EXIT", false)) {
            finish();
        }  

        setContentView(R.layout.dlayout);

        Button play;

        play = (Button) findViewById(R.id.dId);     

        play.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override

        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),ActivityA.class);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
              intent.putExtra("EXIT", true);
               startActivity(intent);

               finish();

        }

        });


    }

}
```

**ActivityE**

```
import java.util.Calendar;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlarmManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;

import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;


public class ActivityE extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getIntent().getBooleanExtra("EXIT", false)) {
            finish();
        }  

        setContentView(R.layout.elayout);

        Button play;

        play = (Button) findViewById(R.id.eId);     

        play.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override

        public void onClick(View v) {

            //startActivity(new Intent(ActivityE.this,ActivityE.class));

        }

        });


    }

}
```

Just do this

Comment: Lets have activity stack A-B-C-D. Now I have to open E and also need to finish A,B,C,D. Please explain me where to put which one.

Comment: means you want to go first A then B then C and then D , but before go to E , you would like to finish A-B-C-D right?

Comment: Please reply quick, because I will log out within 15 minutes

Comment: Yes I have to finish A-B-C-D before goes to E

Comment: Is it require for you to go B to A or D to C or C to B before goes to E, then their is an easiest solution before go to any activity finish() A then before go to B to C finish() B and so on........ if any thing else then pleas let me know quickly

Comment: My app is in such a way that user can edit his info that he gave in first four pages A-B-C-D. So I should not finish the each activity while opening next activity. Once he confirm in activity D the I have to close all the previous activity.

Answer (score 1):

Set following flags:

```
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
```

`FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK` is available from api 11 though.

Comment: Thanks! For my app  android:minSdkVersion="4". Any other way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Use finish below.For eg: A->B->C->D from D instead of C if you want to move to B,
 then use `finish()` below.For others leave as it is or you can also use

`android:noHistory="true" in manifest.`

ie

```
Intent i=new Intent(C.this,D.class);
startActivity(i);
finish();
```

if you click back from D, C activity won't be displaced. It skips to B activity unless if you didn't given `finish();` if you declared `finish()` in B, then skip to A activity.Similarly you can do it. or you can also use `android:noHistory="true"`

[Start Activity clearing top in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16211678/start-activity-clearing-top-in-android/16211826#16211826)

Comment: My app is in such a way that user can edit his info that he gave in first four pages A-B-C-D. So I should not finish the each activity while opening next activity. Once he confirm in activity D the I have to close all the previous activity.

Answer (score 0):

use following code in `ActivityE`... don't use `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK`

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActivityD.class);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do that.

```
While moving from A -> B, finish() A, and move to B.
While moving from B -> C, finish() B, and move to C.
While moving from C -> D, finish() C, and move to D.
While moving from D -> E, just move to E. (dont finish activity D)
```

This way, D will be the first activity in stack.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 Intent i = new Intent(CurrentActivity.this,NextActivity.class);
    // Closing all the Activities
    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
   // Add new Flag to start new Activity
    i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
   // Staring NewActivity
    startActivity(i);
    finish();
```

`android:noHistory="true"` in manifest.

Answer (score 0):

While moving to activity E don't finish you r activity D.
means remove your flag line `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK`

only write

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActivityD.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(intent);
```

and add line `android:noHistory="true"` in your manifest.