# Android finish Activity and then resume Activity parent

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, onresume

MainActivity --(starts)--> LoginActivity--(if login success)-->MainActivity (with updated data).

I want to finish LoginActivity then start MainActivity with layout login successfull

I've tried with this code :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Synchronization.this, MainActivity.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
startActivity(intent);
this.finish();
```

but it's not working properly. Any ideas how to get the things to work properly?

Comment: add more information to understand your problem

Comment: It's very easy yesterday I have solved this kind of same problem. Follow this tutorial and get full answer:: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20995643/finish-activity-in-backstack-android/20996131#20996131 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20995643/finish-activity-in-backstack-android/20996131#20996131

Comment: follow my answer and get solution

Answer (score 1):

have a try with

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Synchronization.this, MainActivity.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could only finish LoginActivity ,not need start Activity again . You could update data on onResume of MainActivity

I am sorry for my bad English