# Android Pop activity from the bottom of activities task/stack

Tags: android, android-intent

I have three Activities A, B,C Now I am Moving  Activities like A -> B->C 
Now I want to show Activity A form C. without creating new Activity. That means I have to show old "A".
Can u please tell me how to achieve it.

Comment: Please see my answer you will get you answer most probably

Comment: possible duplicate of [Finish Activity in BackStack - Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20995643/finish-activity-in-backstack-android)

Comment: Do you want to bring `A` forward so that your activity stack looks like `B->C->A` (wuith `A` on top)? or do you want to remove `B` and `C` from the stack so that you only have `A` in the stack?

Answer (score 1):

Use [`FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT). See linked docs for details.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to bring particular activity on top, then do this

```
    yourIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
```

If you want to close all your running activities except a particular activity, do this

```
    yourIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
```

Comment: In above case only `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT` will work.