# How to clear the stack activities without clearing the root activity, and bring the root activity to front?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-lifecycle

I searched a lot of threads and implemented a lot of solutions but I think I want something else. 
Suppose I have A->B->C->D activities. From activity D I wont to go to the same instance of A and also clear D,C,B activities. I want to resume activity A and not recreate it! How can I do that? But remember, I want also to clear all the other activities, so I in the stack I should have only activity A.

Thank you! :)

Comment: Check this thread for your answer:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16211678/start-activity-clearing-top-in-android

Comment: @kjurkovic: The one who asks the question wants a new instance, I want the same instance

Comment: if you even bothered to read his question, you'd notice he gave you an answer: "By the way I'm using a
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP); 
when launching the B activity but this way the onNewIntent is called instead of start a new instance"

Answer (score 0):

just do on back button , Try to call your intent with the flag "BROUGHT TO FRONT"

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this,A.class);
intent .setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_BROUGHT_TO_FRONT);
startActivity(intent );
```

Comment: Ok by means you wants to clear Activities C and B also but wants the older activity A which was saved, than you need to handle in such a way that you can use Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP up to activity B and than call finish() smartly based on some savedPreference value at level B!!

Comment: Hmm this should do it. I will try it and ask you to post an answer so I can mark it! Thx

Comment: use a saved preference boolean value at activity B and check if boolean is true or false if boolean is having yours desired value than finish  and at last activity D use Intent DtoB = new Intent(this,B.class);
DtoB .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(DtoB );

Answer (score 0):

Assuming activity 'A' is the root of the task of your application - Using the flag *CLEAR_TASK* along with *NEW_TASK* will portray the same behaviour as yours. All you need to do is add these flags in the intent for activity 'A'.

The flag *CLEAR_TASK* will remove all the activities on top on 'A' and *NEW_TASK* will create a new task with 'A' (same activity instance) as its root.

Hope this helps